# Using chain rule to find $\frac{dz}{dt}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know what the chain rule is but i am unsure how to apply it to this case.

$$z=x^3\cdot e^{2y}$$

$$x=2t$$

$$y=t^2$$

**Edit:** Fixed title to $\frac{dz}{dt}$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to find $\frac{dz}{dt}$ instead of $\frac{dz}{dx}$?

Comment: Omg you are right im sorry it is dz/dt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the [multivariable chain rule](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/multichainrule/):
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dt} \tag{1}$$
Simply evaluate the ordinary and partial derivatives, and substitute them into the equation above. You should have a result for $\frac{dz}{dt}$ in terms of $x,y$ and $t$. Then, substitute the parametrizations for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ to obtain an expression for $\frac{dz}{dt}$ strictly in terms of $t$ as done on the first example of the [link](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/multichainrule/) I provided.

---

Let's start by evaluating $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$. Since we must treat the variable $y$ as a constant as a result of **partial** differentiation, $e^{2y}$ is also treated as one. Therefore:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=3x^2\cdot e^{2y}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Thank you I'll try this and get back to you

Comment: Okay I calculated the partial and normal derivites but I dont understand where to plug them in.   The derivitive dx/dt =2, dy/dt= 2t,          partial x = 3x^2x e^(2y) and partial y as 2e^(2y)

Comment: @Clueless Plug them in to equation $(1)$. Out of curiosity, what did you evaluate each of the derivatives to be?

Comment: The derivitive dx/dt =2, dy/dt= 2t, partial x = 3x^2x e^(2y) and partial y=2e^(2y)

Comment: @Clueless Did you make a typo? For $z=x^3\cdot e^{2y}$ you should obtain:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=3x^2\cdot e^{2y}$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2x^3\cdot e^{2y}$$
Otherwise, the rest are correct.

Comment: No typo I had the wrong answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @Clueless No problem. Do you know why your partial derivatives turned out wrong? If so, just plug in your partial derivatives like this:
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=\color{red}{3x^2\cdot e^{2y}}\cdot \color{green}{2}+\color{blue}{2x^3\cdot e^{2y}} \cdot \color{orange}{2t}$$
And now substitute $x=2t$ and $y=t^2$ for $x$ and $y$ to obtain an explicit expression for $\frac{dz}{dt}$ in terms of $t$.

Simply follow the methodology provided by the [first example](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/multichainrule/).